# How to get point(x,y,z) on a custom 3d model from uv coordinate?

Tags: graphics, vertex, uv-mapping

How can I get the XYZ position with UV coordinate?
I heard that I could use barycentric coordinates to get XYZ on a 3d object.
But I am not sure how to calculate it.
[image]